postgresql getting data between characters : and ] differing lengths of data between characters
New to data mining like this. My first post. Apologies if I did something wrong.
This is my data in the field. I cannot use length because I have different formats and lengths in the data.

[PICK] [LOCTN    : 42-08-A-01]

What I want is

42-08-A-01

Tried these 3 select statements and they all came back the same way with the last right bracket.

SUBSTRING(table.field from '[LOCTN]    : (.*?[^|:]]+)') AS test


split_part(wa.fx,':', 2) AS SUB1


(regexp_split_to_array(wa.fx, ':'::text))[2] AS STUFF

How can I get that last right bracket out?

42-08-A-01]


Using left()
left(split_part(wa.fx,':', 2), -1) AS SUB1

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html

Nick, Thank you so much. Spot on! Somehow I knew this was going to be a simple update but kept finding examples that didn't quite fit the bill.

@LApd2024 Nice! Since it has helped, could you please accept the answer (click on the tick)

Hey Nick I hit the green tick but I can't up vote it because of my new reputation... sigh
